# 'Member not found. 0x80020003, my Do loop needs a catch all if search variable not found

Tags: excel, vb.net

I have a mixture of loops/if statements. I have entered break mode and it works the first and second time around, then falls apart the third time and throws the runtime error. The third time around, somehow the `tmp = Nothing` gets passed my initial try at a "catch" to make `tmp = "Not Found"`. Would love any input.

```
'Convert HEX values to acronyms
            'Define variables for converting Hex values to acronyms
            Dim k As Integer : k = 0
            Dim found As Integer : found = 0
            Dim tmp As String
            Dim current_string As String
            Dim name_start As Integer
            Dim sym As Object
            sym = xlWorkBook.Sheets("sym")
            hex_value = unique_pgns.Range("A" & i).Value
            Do While found = 0
                k = k + 1
                current_string = sym.Range("A" & k).Value
                name_start = InStr(current_string, hex_value)
                If name_start = 6 Then
                    found = 1
                End If
                If k = 32766 Then
                    'To do: current_string was not found
                    found = 1
                    tmp = "Not found"
                    unique_pgns.Range("B" & i) = tmp
                    i = i + 1
                End If

            Loop

            tmp = sym.Range("A" & k - 1).Value
            tmp = Replace(tmp, "[", "")
            tmp = Replace(tmp, "]", "")

            unique_numbers.Range("B" & i) = tmp ' Error occurs here on the third time around.
            i = i + 1
        Loop
```

hehe

Comment: To me, I suspect the actual error might be in this line tmp = sym.Range("A" & k - 1).Value.  I would start by looking at the value of k at that point to ensure it is what you expect and what tmp equals immediately after that line is executed.  I'm wondering if k might be 1, then it leaves you looking at cell A0

Comment: I suggest in VS settings you turn on *Option Strict* for VB.NET. Because `.Range("A" & i)` is a string concatenation, but i is defined as an `Integer`, which shouldn't work with the above setting, as it would require an explicit type conversion (`ToString`). You currently rely on VB.NET's guesstimation and implicit type conversion ... which *works* most of the time, but if it *fails*, it's a nightmare to spot/debug/correct.

Comment: @HelO'Ween, appreciate that insight. I turned on Option Strict and there were not syntax errors invoked on the code. `.Range("A" & i)` is the Column and corresponding Row number. Then I pull that value of the cell which is a string.

Comment: @Hursey, I have found the issue, but will need thoughts on how to do it. After walking through break again, I see that the issue is I get all the way to the used rows for `k = 32766` and did not find the `hex_value` in that sheet. I need a catch all if not found then move to the next row in the column. The runtime occurs because `tmp = Nothing` and `sym.Range("A" & k - 1).Value` is at the end. Where should I put the catch?

Comment: I'm not really sure I'm understanding your question.  If you need a Catch, the you also need a try.  Perhaps some reading on Try/Catch might be in order? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/try-catch-finally-statement  That aside, you could always just check If tmp IsNot Nothing with an if statement before attempting to do any further work on it